# What is the symbol on the supply voltage that looks like a shaded-in capacitor?

Tags: schematics

I am looking at [a datasheet for NJM2073](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/294/NJM2073_E-275459.pdf) (dual low-voltage power amplifier). On the fourth page, there is a sample circuit; right at the V+ input there is a symbol that looks like a capacitor. However, it looks like it is shaded in. What is that?

[image]

Comment: It's an electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: What @LeonHeller said.

Comment: It is a Japanese electrolytic capacitor

Comment: @PeterBennett A "Japanese electrolytic capacitor" is not the same thing as the symbol that Japanese use for a capacitor. A "Japanese electrolytic capacitor" is like referring to a component manufactured in Japan when this is just about different standards for representing components in a schematic.

Comment: @alexan_e: Sorry - I should have used a smiley :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Intercontinental symbols for fixed capacitor from [here](https://sound-au.com/beginners.htm):

[image: Capacitor Symbols]

and from http://www.learnabout-electronics.org:

[image: Capacitor Symbols]

and a very old one....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### This is a polarized (electrolytic) capacitor

While all the schematic symbols used for capacitors will have two lines or a line and a curve in parallel, thus *looking* like a parallel-plate capacitor, the precise nature of these symbols varies across region.  EIA (North American) practice uses a parallel-line-and-curve symbol for a non-polarized capacitor and adds a + polarity marker on the line side for polarized electrolytics, while IEC/EN (European) practice uses a two-line symbol for non-polarized capacitors and a line-and-box symbol with the box on the + side, along with the + sign for polarity, for polarized capacitors, and EIAJ (Japanese) practice is to use the shading/crosshatching between the two lines to denote polarity instead of the box,  as they use the two-line symbol as well.

BTW: if you're wondering why the US uses the line-and-curve capacitor symbol, it's to avoid confusion with the parallel-lines symbol used for relay, and more importantly *contactor*, contacts in industrial electrical work (such as ladder logic diagrams and industrial wiring diagrams).